# Sort alphabetically Users

Tags: development, asp.net, user-accounts

When I'm Adding users, i want to sort them alphabetically. Could You help. Here is my code:

```
     SPUserCollection userzyWszyscy2 = witryna.SiteUsers;
        foreach (SPUser oUserKolejny in userzyWszyscy2)
        {

            DropDownList1.Items.Add(oUserKolejny.LoginName);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lean towards using Linq for this:

```
var listItems = from SPUser u in userzyWszyscy2
order by u.LoginName select new ListItem(u.LoginName)

DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(listItems.ToArray());
```

hope this helps, it is from memory without my trusty IDE to help ;)